# I have problem in the 'removeElement(element)' in the doubly linked list

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures, doubly-linked-list

I am facing a problem in the remove element in the list. When I want to remove the element in the list it not able to remove but other function works properly such as adding and removing at index.

```
 class Node{
constructor(element){
    this.element = element;
    this.right = null;
    this.left = null;
}
}

class DLinkList{
constructor(){
    this.head = null;
    this.tail = null;
    this.size = 0;
}

addFront(element){
    var node = new Node(element);

    var curr;

    if(this.head === null){
        this.head = node;
        this.tail = node;
    }else{
        this.head.left = node;
        node.right = this.head;
        this.head = node;
    }
    this.size++;
}

addAtIndex(element,index){
    var node = new Node(element);

    var curr,prev;

    if(this.head === null){
        this.head = node;
        this.tail = node;
    }else{
        var it = 0;

        curr = this.head;
        while(it < index){
            it++;
            prev = curr;
            curr = curr.right;
        }
        node.right = curr;
        prev.right = node;
        node.left = prev;
    }
    this.size++;
}

removeAtIdex(index){
    var curr,prev, it = 0;
    if(index > 0 && index > this.size){
        return false;
    }else{
        curr = this.head;
        while(it < index){
            it++;
            prev = curr;
            curr = curr.right;
        }
        prev.right = curr.right;
        curr.right.left = prev;
    }
    this.size--;
}

removeElement(element){
    var curr,prev = null;

    curr = this.head;
    while(curr != null){
        if(curr.element === element){
            if(prev === null){
                this.head = curr.right;
            }else{
                prev.right = curr.right;
            }
            this.size--;
        }
        prev = curr;
        curr = curr.next;
    }
    return -1;
}

printList(){
    var curr = this.head;
    var str = ''
    while(curr){
        str += curr.element + ' ';
        curr = curr.right;
    }
    console.log(str);

}
}

var ll = new DLinkList();
ll.addFront(2);
ll.addFront(3);
ll.addFront(4);
ll.addAtIndex(5,2);
ll.printList(); 
ll.removeAtIdex(1);
ll.printList();
ll.removeElement(5);
ll.printList();
console.log(ll);
```

**output:**

```
4 3 5 2

4 5 2

4 5 2


DLinkList {
  head: Node {
   element: 4,
   right: Node { element: 5, right: [Node], left: [Circular] },
   left: null
  },
  tail: Node {
   element: 2,
   right: null,
   left: Node { element: 3, right: [Node], left: [Node] }
  },
  size: 3
}
```

Comment: What precisely is the "problem"?

Comment: I don't know where is your problem in `removeElement`, but your `this.head` always is `null`, so I think your `while loop` never work right?

Comment: Putnam--   my other function work properly but when i want to remove any particular element then it not able to remove from list...

Comment: Paste the complete code please. Where's the method to add the elements to the list?

Comment: Perhaps you would benefit by giving your nodes unique ids and basing your searches on that.

Comment: when i editing my complete code it shows me error

Comment: Please be more specific. Which error? In which line? While editing or while running? Please provide the code with which you have tested your code, and which illustrates that the result is wrong, or generates an exception. Be precise. *"I'm having a problem"* is not a good problem description.

Comment: @trincot --- I really apologies for that.. but now i am edited my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use a non-existing property name: `next`. There is no `curr.next`. It should be `curr.right`.

Also, don't forget to update  `left` and `tail`:

```
    if (curr.right === null) {
        this.tail = prev;
    } else {
        curr.right.left = prev;
    }
```